# Accessing google drive by running cron job

Tags: php, php-7, google-oauth, google-drive-realtime-api

Here I am using google drive to backup my data on drive and for that I wrote a script which i want to run through cronjob. but it needs access_token to access google drive. I am keeping access token in my db and providing it to backup file but that token is not getting updated through cronjob . but when I am running it on browser then working fine. I want to update token through cronjob which didn't get updated.

**oauth2callback.php**

```
<?php
    require_once '../inc/google/vendor/autoload.php';
    require_once '../classes/dbconnection.class.php';

    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setAuthConfigFile('client_secret.json');
    $client->setAccessType("offline");
    $client->setRedirectUri('https://******/controllers/oauth2callback.php');
    $client->addScope(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE);

    if (! isset($_GET['code'])) {
        $auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();
        header('Location: ' . filter_var($auth_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
    } else {
        $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
        $token_data = $client->getAccessToken();
        update_token($token_data);
        $redirect_uri = 'https://******/controllers/db_backup.php?action=backup';
        header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
    }

    function update_token($data){
        $db = new dbconnection;
        $conn = $db->connect('pf_central'); 

        $update_token = $conn->query("UPDATE google_drive_token SET access_token = '{$data['access_token']}', token_type = '{$data['token_type']}', expires_in = '{$data['expires_in']}', created = '{$data['created']}' WHERE id = '1'");

    }

?>
```

**db_backup.php**

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
require_once '../classes/dbconnection.class.php';


$week = array(
                   'Sun' => '0',
                   'Mon' => '1',
                   'Tue' => '2',
                   'Wed' => '3',
                   'Thu' => '4',
                   'Fri' => '5',
                   'Sat' => '6'
                );

$folder = array(
                   'Sun' => '0B7nanNCGzXwLbmx3emVQNFBLNlU',
                   'Mon' => '0B7nanNCGzXwLb0hDTWFLVmNza3c',
                   'Tue' => '0B7nanNCGzXwLaVFtRkVRcUU0NFE',
                   'Wed' => '0B7nanNCGzXwLdlFwQVZuOURSZjA',
                   'Thu' => '0B7nanNCGzXwLSUhBMnVQVWpVUzQ',
                   'Fri' => '0B7nanNCGzXwLUGJmOFJId19TVGs',
                   'Sat' => '0B7nanNCGzXwLcnhhV2tvMUdFNkk'
                );

if($_GET['action'] == 'backup' || $_GET['action'] == 'Backup' || $_GET['action'] == 'BACKUP' || $_GET['action'] == 'backup#'){
    require_once '../inc/google/vendor/autoload.php';   
    require_once '../classes/dumper.class.php';

    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setAuthConfigFile('client_secret.json');
    $client->setAccessType("offline"); 
    $client->addScope(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE);

    $db = new dbconnection;
    $conn = $db->connect('pf_central');

    $token_data = $conn->query("SELECT access_token,token_type,expires_in,created FROM google_drive_token WHERE id = '1'")->fetch_assoc();

    //var_dump($token_data);

    if (isset($token_data) && $token_data) {

        $client->setAccessToken($token_data);
        $drive_service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
       // $files_list = $drive_service->files->listFiles(array())->getFiles();


        $timestamp = strtotime(date("Y-m-d"));
        $day = date("D", $timestamp);


        $backup_result = $conn->query("SELECT `cd`.`db_name`,`b`.`backup`,`b`.`id`,`b`.`file_id`,`b`.`file_name` FROM `client_db` AS `cd` INNER JOIN `backup` AS `b` ON `cd`.`id` = `b`.`client_id` WHERE `b`.`backup` <> '2' AND `day_code` = '{$week[$day]}' ");

        if($backup_result->num_rows ){

            while ($row = $backup_result->fetch_assoc()){

                try {
                    if($row['backup'] == 0){ 
                        if(isset($row['file_id']) && !empty($row['file_id']))
                            deleteFile($drive_service,$row['file_id']);

                        $world_dumper = Shuttle_Dumper::create(array(
                            'host' => 'localhost',
                            'username' => 'Joeroot',
                            'password' => '*****',
                            'db_name' => $row['db_name'],
                        ));

                        $zipFilename = $row['db_name'].'.sql.gz';
                        $world_dumper->dump($zipFilename); // if dump is not working then please check a folder perimission and change it to '777'

                        $update_backup = $conn->query("UPDATE `backup` SET `backup`= '1',`file_name`='{$zipFilename}' WHERE `id` = '{$row['id']}' ");

                         $file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile(array(
                                  'name' =>$zipFilename ,
                                  'parents' => array($folder[$day])
                                ));
                         $result = $drive_service->files->create($file, array(
                                        'data' => file_get_contents($zipFilename),
                                        'mimeType' => 'application/octet-stream',
                                        'uploadType' => 'multipart'
                                    ));

                        if($result['id']){
                            $update_backup = $conn->query("UPDATE `backup` SET `backup`= '2',`file_id`='{$result['id']}',`file_name`='{$zipFilename}' WHERE `id` = '{$row['id']}' ");
                            unlink($zipFilename);

                        }
                    }
                    else if($row['backup'] == 1){
                        $file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile(array(
                                  'name' =>$row['file_name'] ,
                                  'parents' => array($folder[$day])
                                ));

                        $result = $drive_service->files->create($file, array(
                                        'data' => file_get_contents($row['file_name']),
                                        'mimeType' => 'application/octet-stream',
                                        'uploadType' => 'multipart'
                                    ));

                        if($result['id']){
                            $update_backup = $conn->query("UPDATE `backup` SET `backup`= '2',`file_id`='{$result['id']}',`file_name`='{$row['file_name']}' WHERE `id` = '{$row['id']}' ");
                            unlink($row['file_name']);
                        }
                    }

                } catch(Shuttle_Exception $e) {
                    //$update_backup = $conn->query("UPDATE `backup` SET `backup`= '0',`file_name`='{$zipFilename}' WHERE `id` = '{$row['id']}' ");
                }
            }
        }
        else
            echo "No data to backup";

    } else {
        $redirect_uri = 'https://papa.fit/controllers/oauth2callback.php';
        header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
    }
}

else if ($_GET['action'] == 'reSchedule' || $_GET['action'] == 'RESCHEDULE' || $_GET['action'] == 'reschedule' ) {
    $db = new dbconnection;
    $conn = $db->connect('pf_central');

    $timestamp = strtotime(date("Y-m-d"));
    $day = date("D", $timestamp);

    $update_backup = $conn->query("UPDATE `backup` SET `backup`= '0' WHERE `day_code` = '{$week[$day]}' "); 

    if($update_backup)
        echo "Resheduled databases for next backup";
}

function deleteFile($service, $fileId) {
  try {
    $service->files->delete($fileId);
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
  }
}   

?>
```

Comment: Getting an access token requires a user to personally authorize an app. However once a user has done that you can just store the access token for as long as it remains valid (most OAuth2 services can also renew it when it expires without user interaction). Point is this won't work unless you already have an access token to work with.

Comment: Initially i have that in my db but it is getting expired after sometime. rather I can refresh it by calling oauth2callback.php and store it in db for next use. but cron is unable to refresh that token because of call back event (I think).

Comment: The process to refresh a token is not the same as the process to reacquire. This might help https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#offline

Comment: sounds good . can you help me with above code @apokryfos. because I have set it for offline access if you see above.

Comment: What should be the next step to get token through cronjob.

Comment: I can't help with the specifics but the source I gave you says "devices all obtain refresh tokens **during the authorization process**", so you probably need to set the access type to offline when you're getting the token. Other than that maybe someone with more experience using the Google API can help.